# Unable to set cookie between React and express

Tags: reactjs, heroku, cookies, session-cookies, netlify

I am trying to set a cookie between my react frontend (on netlify) and my express backend (on heroku). My code does work perfectly fine in localhost but not in production. In production I am getting an 500 server error and the cookie is not being set on the frontend. (If I remove the code that set the cookie on the backend, the code works as expected).

I know this question has been answered but I am still unable to find a solution.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here some links I tried

[Cross-Domain Session Cookie (Express API on Heroku + React App on Netlify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503751/cross-domain-session-cookie-express-api-on-heroku-react-app-on-netlify)

[Not able to set/receive cookies cross-domain using Netlify and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025703/not-able-to-set-receive-cookies-cross-domain-using-netlify-and-heroku)

[Cookie sent to localhost but not to https domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600755/cookie-sent-to-localhost-but-not-to-https-domain)

My code:

Index.ts (express)

```js
import express from "express";
import routes from "./routes";
import connectToDb from "./utils/connectToDb.util";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import apiError from "./middlewares/apiError.middleware";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import deserializeUser from "./middlewares/deserializeUser";
import cors from "cors";
import session from "cookie-session";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(
  cors({ origin: true, credentials: true, exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"] })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(deserializeUser);

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "dede",
    sameSite: "none",
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    secure: false,
  })
);

app.use(routes);
app.use(apiError);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`);

  connectToDb();
});
```

Login Controller (express)

```js
export const login = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, UserLoginInput>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const user = await findUserByEmail(req.body.email);

    if (!user) {
      return next(UserError.invalidInputError("email"));
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await user.validatePassword(req.body.password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return next(UserError.invalidInputError("password"));
    }

    const jwt_token = createToken(user._id);

    res.cookie("jwt_token", jwt_token, {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: "https://website.com",
      sameSite: "none",
    });

    res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR in login", error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

Api call (React)

```js
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL || "http://localhost:5000";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL + "/api/users",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const response = await api.post("/login", { email, password });

  console.log(response);

  return response.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently got the same issue, I can clearly see the cookie in the response, but somehow it didn't show up in the browser store. And I also tried the links you mentioned above, trying to set up `sameSite`,`secure` and `domain` properties and etc. None of them worked out in my case. But in the end I deployed my frontend app and backend app under the same url on Heroku following a video I found on youtube, the link is here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dQC2JUd27g, hopefully, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I should have tried this solution way earlier... It's working fine now. Thanks again !!!

Comment: @tartiesorel Hey, it's okay, no need to be sorry about that. Actually, I'm glad things working out on your side. And one more thing, just in case next time when bumping into a similar situation again, make sure to either host our fontend and backend in one place under the same domain or give each a different  subdomain if you wanna host them in different places, and the only thing needs to pay attention to is make sure those subdomains are under the same parent domain, then you are good to go. Happy coding :)